# Jquery array of objects

Tags: jquery

I have an array of objects in session. This has been populated in select list. based on the selected item from the list, I would have to pre-populate the form with the attributes of the object selected.

Please help.

- Aanu

Comment: Please provide what server technology you are using; clarify what you mean by "session" (Traditional PHP $_SESSION, etc); Finally, post what you have tried so far.

Comment: its a java session. I just populated the select as under.
#foreach( $emp in $allEmp)
  <option value=
#end

on select of one employee I would have to populate the values related to that employee on the form (such as sex, dob, city etc.,). I am trying to do this using jquery.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could store employee information into a javascript object:

```
var employees = [
    { id: '1', sex: 'm', city: 'Paris' }, 
    { id: '2', sex: 'f', city: 'London' },
    ... etc fill this in a foreach loop
];
```

Next you bind to the change event of the select box:

```
$(function()
{
    $('select#id_of_the_employees_select').change(function(e) {
        // Get the current selected employee id
        var selectedEmployeeId = $(this).val();
        // find the corresponding employee in the list
        var emps = $.grep(employees, function(n, i) {
            return n.id == selectedEmployeeId;
        });
        if (emps.length > 0) {
            var employee = emps[0];
            // fill the form elements with employee data:
            $('#employee_sex').val(employee.sex);
            $('#employee_city').val(employee.city);
        }
    });
});
```